# PHP preg_replace: use variable

Tags: php, preg-replace

I'm having a problem using a variable from preg_replace.
Basically what I want to achieve is to look for some patterns in a text, and replace them by content. The replacement is done in a seperate function (retrieveValue() ). However I'm having difficulties passing the variable ('$1').

```
$types = array(
        array(
                '/\*#(.*?)#\*/',
                $this->retrieveValue($templateVars,'$1')    
             )
        );

    foreach ($types as $type) {
        $template = preg_replace($type[0], $type[1], $template);
    }
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The problem is that `$this->retrieveValue($templateVars,'$1')` is executed **before** you call `preg_replace`.

**Solution:** Have a look at [`preg_replace_callback`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.preg-replace-callback.php).

I suggest you create a new method in your class:

```
public function _replace($matches) {
    return $this->retrieveValue($templateVars, $matches[1]);
}
```

and then can use:

```
preg_replace_callback('/\*#(.*?)#\*/', array($this, '_replace'), $template);
```

---

You can also make use of [anonymous functions](http://php.net/manual/en/functions.anonymous.php) in PHP 5.3.

Comment: Thanks this seems to be working, however is it possible to pass additional parameters to the _replace function (in addition to the $matches) ?

Comment: @user485659: No. But if you use PHP 5.3 you can use anonymous functions and closures.

Comment: @user485659: If you need to pass further parameters and you don't have PHP 5.3, have a look at [`create_function`](http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.create-function.php). Maybe you can somehow add the parameters differently.